# Can't compile and run code when joining vscode live share session

Tags: visual-studio-code, collaboration, vscode-liveshare

When I join a live share session in vscode, I can neither compile, nor run the code. The arrow on the top left doesn't even show. When pressing F5 to compile, vscode just asks me to find Python extensions to be able to debug the code.

In a hosting a session or coding by myself, everything works fine. We used live share yesterday and it worked flawlessly too.
Any ideas?

Comment: if you want to co-debug, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/codebug-visual-studio-code. do those docs help? Or do you want the guest to be able to debug independently of the host and of each other?